# How do I correctly display the content of an environment variable (here: current user's home directory)?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

If I type

```
echo home
```

I will only see the word "home" as output and not the "home/user"

I am the only user on this machine and have a password.

Why do I get the wrong output and what do I have to change to display my user's home directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** Variables in Linux start with the `$`.

---

The command is

```
echo $HOME
```

If you type in

```
printenv
```

it will show you all the variables and what they equal.

Or

```
printenv | grep '^HOME='
```

or a few more you can try:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ echo ~
/home/terrance
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ printf "%b \n" ~
/home/terrance 
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ printf "%b \n" $HOME
/home/terrance
```

Comment: @A.B. Why are you trying to copy some part of my answer and added to this answer?!

Comment: I gave you a hint and this answer is eight hours old. And before I gave you the hint, I improved this answer.

Comment: @A.B. you should improve before I added this part?!!!!!

Comment: @Maythux comments are not for starting a war. If you got problems with A.B. drop into Ubuntu chat and explain your problem to a AU moderator (Seth or Oli for instance). Or create a topic in Meta asking what is proper etiquette ;) comments though are not the correct place.

Comment: @Rinzwind It's not my problem! I didn't start this war, and I don't trust most moderators unfair, anyway I don't want anything and I don't want to make any war, But I hate those guys who try to be clever in time hurting others. You can yourself see the history and know who start the war!!! Thanks

Comment: @Maythux Please explain how is the edit a copy of your answer?

Comment: @Mitch look at the time of edit and to my answer, specially he gives a note on that specific point, then he just added to this answer

Comment: @Maythux with all due respect, your answer is good (and I was one of the ones upvoting yours ), but I'm looking at revision history side by side right now for both answers, and it says 'edited 49 mins ago' for your second edit, while second edit for Terrance's answer where A.B. first added the line says ' edited 55 mins ago ', so technically A.B.'s edit came earlier.

Comment: @Serg his edit is a part of my answer, why he added that part?! why he didn't add before my answer?! I really don't want to speak about I just want to have some peace here, I really become uncomfortable and unhappy here

Comment: @Maythux let it go, we're talking about a couple of seconds :)

Comment: @Mitch I forget about, I really don't care about result I care about way of dealing with me. I hate this discrimination  in dealing, that's all my problem. I don't care about an up here or there, my problem is much bigger

Answer (score 4):

To print an environment variable you should use the `$` sign before. So what you are doing in

```
echo home
```

this will just print the word home since the shell will not expand the variable home since it's not started with `$` sign, and it should be capitalized.

So to have the output you should run:

```
echo $HOME
```

To list all environment variables you can use the command `env`.

Also you can get the same result of `echo $HOME` by running the command:

```
env | grep '^HOME'
```

**Now** there is some cases when you create a new user without home directory, this may happen if you use the command `useradd` without the `-d` option or without declaring the variables `HOME_DIR` and `BASE_DIR`. So if you create this user using the `useradd` command this would be the case.

Some useful links:

- [How to add users in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto)
- [What are environment vaiables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: `env | grep HOME | head -1                                                                                                                                                        ` gives `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Comment: @A.B. This related to your env, ok i'll fix it

Comment: @A.B. Why are you trying to copy some part of my answer and added to the other answer?!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you explicitly created your user account with no home, all users should get a home directory. In terminal there's a variety you could access it. `cd` is one, `cd ~` is one. Just to see the path to it, do `cd; pwd`, or `echo ~`, or `echo $HOME`, or

```
awk -F ':' -v myusername=$(whoami) ' $0~myusername  { print $6 }' /etc/passwd
```

This last one uses output of `whoami` command to search for appropriate line in `/etc/passwd` file, and prints the 6th item in that line with : as field separator)